# Adjugate of adjacency matrix of a directed bipartite graph

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $G $ be a directed bipartite graph and $A $ be its biadjacency matrix. Is it correct to say that the classical adjoint/adjugate of $A $ is the biadjacency matrix of the graph obtained by reversing all orientations in $G $? If so, what is the proof of this result?

Answer (score 1):

No, just because if you reverse the direction of all the edges, the new adjacency matrix will be the transpose of the old one, not the adjugate.